# #1005 - Can't create table errno: 150 Magento

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I am trying to create a new table for magento and I am trying to reference existing magento tables. From what I googled, the problem that I am getting can be 1 of the 2 issues.

1. The FK must have a index
2. The PK must exist before the FK can reference

In both cases, I believe I did both of these correctly. Below is existing table schemas

## ALREADY EXISTING TABLES BEING REFERENCED

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `core_store` (
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `FK_STORE_WEBSITE` (`website_id`),
  KEY `is_active` (`is_active`,`sort_order`),
  KEY `FK_STORE_GROUP` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores' AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_user` (
  `user_id` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `logdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lognum` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reload_acl_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `extra` text,
  `failures_num` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `first_failure` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lock_expires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_ADMIN_USER_USERNAME` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Users' AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;
```

## Table I am trying to create

```
CREATE TABLE `oro_dashboard` 
( `id` int unsigned NOT NULL, 
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`description` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', 
`created_by` int unsigned NOT NULL default '0', 
`created_at` date, 
`layout` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`default_store_id` int, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
KEY `IDX_ORO_DASHBOARD_CREATED_BY` (`created_by`), 
CONSTRAINT `FK_ORO_DASHBOARD_CREATED_BY_ADMIN_USER_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `admin_user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
CONSTRAINT `FK_ORO_DASHBOARD_DEFAULT_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`default_store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ) 
ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

In magento, I found there is in deed a table called admin_user that does have a column called user_id. There is a core_store table that does have a column called store_id. and both my columns have INDEXES made.

Does anyone have any clue what the issue maybe ? Below is my error message

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'db.oro_dashboard' (errno: 150)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the column definition for `default_store_id` does not match `core_store.store_id`. it should be `smallint(5) unsigned` in your table. `created_by` has the same problem, although it did not prevent the table from being created

Answer (score 3):

It is necessary to have data type to be same for the foreign key and its corresponding parent key. The data type is different of the foreign key and its referencing parent key in your table that is why it is giving an error.

`created by` is int unsigned  while `userid` is medium int in parent table

same is problem in the second foreign key

reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 3):

When defining foreign keys, the data type must be the same.

You are defining `core_store.store_id` as `smallint(5) unsigned` and so the referencing column must be the same: `oro_dashboard.default_store_id`.

Do also with `oro_dashboard.created_by`

Final `oro_dashboard` CREATE TABLE query,

```
CREATE TABLE `oro_dashboard` 
( `id` int unsigned NOT NULL, 
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`description` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', 
`created_by` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', 
`created_at` date, 
`layout` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`default_store_id` smallint(5) unsigned,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IDX_ORO_DASHBOARD_CREATED_BY` (`created_by`) ,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_ORO_DASHBOARD_CREATED_BY_ADMIN_USER_USER_ID` 
     FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) 
     REFERENCES `admin_user` (`user_id`) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_ORO_DASHBOARD_DEFAULT_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` 
     FOREIGN KEY (`default_store_id`) 
     REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) 
     ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE 
)
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9819)